# Dropdown open in redirect

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

Is it possible for me to open a dropdown after clicking on some menu item?

I would like to click on "test", be redirected to the page that this dropdown is and open it

```
  <li>
    <Link to="/testdropdown">
      test
    </Link>                                                       
  </li>
```

DROPDOWN:

```
<button  data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#test" >
   test dropdown
 </button>
            
 <div id="test" className="collapse">
     <p>content</p>
  </div>
```

I have a header with some links that lead to another page, this other page has some dropdowns, it is possible that when I click on any of these links I will be redirected to the exact dropdown and with it
open?

All links lead to the same page, only I would like to open specific dropdowns, based on the link I clicked

Example: I have the "test" link, is it possible that when I click on it I go to this page that has the dropdowns but open only this dropdown that refers to "test" and leave all the other dropdowns closed?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you could make the dropdown open by default on the redirected page instead of having it closed which we are used to.

Comment: Can you please elaborate you question ?